# python - print line and list that contains regex match

Tags: python, regex, ip-address, ipv4

I have a log file, at least thousand lines

```
abc.txt:
1. example eg, ham, cheese 350.122.345.8
2. cheese ham eg, example 231.242.1.2
3. Ham cheese, example,e.g 100.200.100.200
4.
5. Ham cheese, example,e.g 100.200.100.200
1000.
```

Final result I want:

Print only those lines that match the number within the ip address range. Hence it should print only:

```
2. cheese ham eg, example 231.242.1.2
3. Ham cheese, example,e.g 100.200.100.200
5. Ham cheese, example,e.g 100.200.100.200
```

I have tried the following code but unable to get the result I want:

```
import re

txt=open('/sdcard/Download/abc.txt','r')

pattern=re.compile('(^[2][0-5][0-5]|^[1]{0,1}[0-9]{1,2})\.([0-2][0-5][0-5]|[1]{0,1}[0-9]{1,2})\.([0-2][0-5][0-5]|[1]{0,1}[0-9]{1,2})\.([0-2][0-5][0-5]|[1]{0,1}[0-9]{1,2})$', re.DOTALL)

for line in txt:
    if str(pattern) in line:
        print line
    else:
        print 'WRONG LINE:',line
```

The result that returns is the full line list printed out and showing my else WRONG LINE message.

I checked my regex with online checker, and it is showing the right behavior, matching all ipv4 addresses, that don't exceed .255

Please point me the mistake.

Comment: `str(pattern) in line` is not what you want. You need something like `re.search` or `re.match`.

Comment: `if re.search(pattern, line) print bla`

Comment: If you use a compiled pattern, you have to use its search or match methods. https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.compile

Comment: also, you could just do `print(str(pattern))` and see that this is not what you want

Comment: @rock321987 It should be something like `if pattern.search(line): print line`

Comment: @wflynny,  I tried,  for line in txt:
    if pattern.search(line):
        print line
    else:
        print 'WRONG LINE:',line  ,  it is still showing all valid ip as wrong line

Comment: @user1935007 That's because your regex is wrong.  You have a '^' in the two beginning match terms which means it's expecting an IP address at the start of the line.  Remove that and it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the corrected regex and code:

```
import re

txt= {"1. example eg, ham, cheese 350.122.345.8",
      "2. cheese ham eg, example 231.242.1.2",
      "3. Ham cheese, example,e.g 100.200.100.200",
      "4.",
      "5. Ham cheese, example,e.g 100.200.100.200"}


pattern=re.compile('([2][0-5][0-5]|[1]{0,1}[0-9]{1,2})\.([0-2][0-5][0-5]|[1]{0,1}[0-9]{1,2})\.([0-2][0-5][0-5]|[1]{0,1}[0-9]{1,2})\.([0-2][0-5][0-5]|[1]{0,1}[0-9]{1,2})', re.DOTALL)

for line in txt:
    if pattern.search(line):
        print line
    else:
        print 'WRONG LINE:',line
```

Answer (score 0):

From: @RudyTheHunter

```
import re

txt=open('/sdcard/Download/abc.txt','r')

pattern=re.compile('([2][0-5][0-5]|[1]{0,1}[0-9]{1,2})\.([0-2][0-5][0-5]|[1]{0,1}[0-9]{1,2})\.([0-2][0-5][0-5]|[1]{0,1}[0-9]{1,2})\.([0-2][0-5][0-5]|[1]{0,1}[0-9]{1,2})', re.DOTALL)

for line in txt:
    if pattern.search(line):
        print line
    else: 
        print 'WRONG LINE:',line
```